# How do I load a tfrecord dataset into a keras model

Tags: tensorflow, keras, tensorflow2.0, tfrecord

I am facing a problem in regards to loading data from a tfrecord file into keras.

The situation is like this: I have a file in tfrecord format, this file contains many pairs of values A and B.

Now I want to load values of type A into my keras model, do some transformations and such to them and then compare the output of my model with values of type B. I then want to minimize the mean squared error between the model output and the values of type B. For all of this it is important that the pairs of values stay "synchronized" together.

The documentation on the tensorflow site only deals with feeding a whole dataset into keras, not with feeding one part into the model and then comparing the output and the other part.

Can anyone point me to examples on how to do this, or explain it?

Answer (score 1):

For the First Question in Loading one part of the TF Record Dataset into Keras Model you can do this by parsing the **'features'** part of the dataset  *(if the TFRecord is in Feature Label pairs)*.

Take note that this also depends on how the TF Record is created.

ie.

```
raw_train_dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset('PATH TO TFRECORD')

# Create a dictionary describing the features.
feature_description = {
    'label': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64),
    'features': tf.io.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
}

def _parse_function(example_proto):
  # Parse the input tf.Example proto using the dictionary above.
  return tf.io.parse_single_example(example_proto, feature_description)

parsed_dataset = raw_train_dataset.map(_parse_function)

for tfrecord_features in parsed_dataset:
  data_raw = tfrecord_features['features'].numpy()
  print(tf.io.decode_raw(data_raw, tf.int64))  // Decode your values into correct data type

   /*** Do whatever you want ***/
```

For the Second one, this should be almost the same on the first one as you only need to compare the values between the processed values of 'features'.
You could try loading the TF Record Dataset using a Function then return the Feature and Label pair.

As for the Third Question can you elaborate further on what exactly you want to achieve as you maybe able to do this after you do the first and second answer.